# (React Native) Displaying a list of cards for items in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, native

I have two arrays, let's say 
word and definition

```html
export default class Dictionary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        word: [],
        definition:[],
        index: 0
    };    
}
```

I have a prop

```
<Card word = {w} definition = {d}/>
```

and I want to display a list of these cards for each word/definition pair in the array. If there are 5 words/definitions, then I want 5 of these cards to display in a ScrollableView. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.The second argument in `Array.prototype.map` function's callback is index. You can use that index to display the corresponding `definition` item like this

```
export default class Dictionary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        word: ["a","b","c"],
        definition:["a","b","c"],
        index: 0
    };    

    render() {
       <div>
       {this.state.word.map((w,i) => {
          return <Card word = {w} definition = {this.state.definition[i]}/> 
       })}
       </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your state you could merge word and definition in one thing like:

```
dictionary: [
  {
    index: 0,
    word: 'Car',
    definition: 'Definition of car',
  },
  // More objects like the one above
]
```

Then write a function that renders this array of objects, could be like:

```
renderDictionary() {
  return (this.state.dictionary.map(word => {
    <Card key={word.index} word={word.word} definition={word.definition} />
  }));
}
```

And then you just call the function:

```
export default class Dictionary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dictionary: [
        {
          index: 0,
          word: 'Car',
          definition: 'Definition of car',
        },
        // More objects like the one above.
      ],
    };
  }

  renderDictionary() {
    return (this.state.dictionary.map(word => {
      <Card key={word.index} word={word.word} definition={word.definition} />
    }));
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderDictionary()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```